# How do you notify when a worker role with service bus queue completes it's processing?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, servicebus

I am trying to create a microservice using the Azure WorkerRoles with Service Bus queue and have it working but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Currently, I am able to connect to the WorkerRole and send a Brokered message with the URI of the image I want to OCR and I am able to run the OCR on the image, but how do I return back to the client that the OCR has completed and the extracted text since it's asynchronous?

Here is my implementation of Client.OnMessage

```
Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
{
    try
    {
        MyServiceBusMessage messageBody = receivedMessage.GetBody<MyServiceBusMessage>();

        // Process the message
        Trace.WriteLine("Processing Service Bus message: " + receivedMessage.SequenceNumber.ToString());
        Trace.WriteLine("Service Bus message ID: " + messageBody.ID);
        Trace.WriteLine("Service Bus message Type: " + messageBody.Type);
        Trace.WriteLine("Service Bus message Image Name: " + messageBody.ImageUri);

        Uri imageURi = messageBody.ImageUri;
        Guid imageGuid = messageBody.ID;

        receivedMessage.Complete();

        string text = DoOCR(imageGuid, imageURi);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        receivedMessage.DeadLetter("Exception Occured", ex.Message);
        // Handle any message processing specific exceptions here
    }
});
```

But now I'm not sure where to go from here and I can't find anything helpful online so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas or hints on where to go next.

Currently I'm using a Console application to send the message to the queue like so:

```
QueueClient client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(constr, queueName);
using (var bMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message))
{
    client.Send(bMessage);
}
```

Can I send a message back to the client letting it know that the OCR has completed with the extracted text? If so, how would I achieve that?

Comment: What type of application is the client that's submitting the messages?

Comment: Currently it's just a console application for testing. I will edit my question with the code I'm using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario you're describing sounds like a typical [Request/Reply](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReply.html) pattern.
You could have another queue your console application would listen to and worker role sending a message upon completion including status and original image ID.

You can also look into frameworks that make it easier to achieve what you're looking for. Have a look at [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/samples/fullduplex/) or MassTransit. Both support different transports and [Azure Service Bus](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/) is one of those.

Side note: I've noticed you're completing your message prior to the OCR work. You might want to change that and complete the message after OCR call is finished. Currently, if `DoOCR()` throws, your message will never be retried since it will be marked as completed.

Comment: Agreed.  You do not .Complete() until you know it was finished correctly.  Sidenote, see this URL for "retrying"  http://markheath.net/post/defer-processing-azure-service-bus-message

Comment: Also take a look at the scatter-gather.  That's what RabbitMQ calls it I think.  http://geekswithblogs.net/asmith/archive/2012/04/16/149332.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I implemented a response queue that the client will subscribe to and wait for a reply from the service.